# Can I get an actual error from a service worker registration?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, sentry

For example, if I have a code like this:

**`script.js`**:

```
// ...
try {
  const serviceWorkerRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js');
  await serviceWorkerRegistration.update();
  // ...
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e); // here I want to get an actual error
}
// ...
```

**`serviceWorker.js`**:

```
// ...
ddd; // the line with an error
// ...
```

Can I get the actual error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: ddd is not defined`) in my `script.js` instead of `TypeError: Failed to update a ServiceWorker for scope (...) ServiceWorker script evaluation failed`? My code is more complex and I see in my Sentry project that some browsers can't parse the service worker script, but I want to understand the reason for that case. Also, I added Sentry client to my service worker, but anyway, an error can be thrown before it's registered.

Answer (score 1):

If there are some browsers that can't parse your code then it really just comes down to transpiling your code to a previous version of javascript. However, if these are tests that you are running then you have a development version that wrap your code in `eval`.

Just to be clear:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ddd is not defined
```

Is a runtime error. It shouldn't be thrown while the engine is parsing your script. However, if you have something like:

```
let [test] = [ddd]
```

You will most likely get a syntax error if your engine doesn't understand ES6 destructuring (even if `ddd` doesn't exist).

This:

```
ddd
```

Can be caught within the service worker script like this

```
self.onerror = e => console.error(e);
ddd;
```

But if it fails at parsing like this... then it won't work:

```
self.onerror = e => console.error(e);
if(
```

However, if you wrap it in an `eval`:

```
self.onerror = e => console.error(e);
eval('if(');
```

Then this work (as `eval` parsing happens on runtime).

Comment: No, it seems like the problem not with ES6 syntax, but maybe with downloading scripts via `importScripts()`. Because the error was in the latest versions of Chromium-based browsers, I tested it by myself in the same versions and it was OK.
I already wrapped my code in `try`/`catch`, I think it's the same as `self.onerror()` callback. But I need the error not in the service worker, but in my `script.js` because I want to send it to Sentry.

Comment: Is it not possible to use Sentry within the service worker?

Comment: Possible, and I use, but in my case it seems like I have an error before Sentry client init.

Comment: If Sentry can't work from the Service Worker script then it's probably not possible. I do not know Sentry but it must obviously be a service consumed through a REST API. I'm unsure if `fetch` or `XMLHTTPRequest` can do cross origin requests through a service worker.

Comment: The error on your question seems to be a parsing error, so it's unlikely that's `importScripts`.

Comment: It works, I tested, but only when an error is thrown after Sentry client is inited.

Comment: The error in the question is just for example. I tested if you have an invalid URL in `importScripts()`, you get the same error from a service worker registration: `ServiceWorker script evaluation failed`.

Comment: I tried as well, I couldn't. Either a parsing error on the script or a bad URL gave me an error that was properly caught by `self.onerror`. It should be the same with a `try/catch`. Maybe it's a bad implementation?

Comment: I need to get the actual error in `script.js`, not in the service worker. There are no problems to caught an error by `self.onerror()` or `try`/`catch`, the problem is to send it to Sentry.